# Реглярное выражение для названия css классов

Tags: javascript

пытаюсь сделать регулярное выражение чтобы можно было вводить название классов, выражение работает но только ругаеться на пробелы как можно сделать что после первого класса можно ввести пробел напри class-1 class class-3  ...

```
let reg = /^([a-z_]|-[a-z_-])[a-z\d_-]*$/;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не лучший вариант но все-же:

```
let classNames = 'class-1 class class-3',
    classes = classNames.split(' '),
    reg = /^([a-z_]|-[a-z_-])[a-z\d_-]*$/;

if(!classes.every((item) => reg.test(item))){
  alert('Class is not valid');
}
```

Мы сначала делим строку по пробелу, а потом каждый подстроку отдельно проверяем на соответствие с регулярным выражением. Если хоть одна подстрока является не корректной, метод `every` вернет `false`.

Можно также убрать мультипробел

```
let classNames = 'class-1 class class-3',
    classes = classNames.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').split(' '),
    reg = /^([a-z_]|-[a-z_-])[a-z\d_-]*$/;

if(!classes.every((item) => reg.test(item))){
    alert('Class is not valid');
}
```

Comment: Я тоже думал использовать split но мне именно в reg нужно както вписать пробелы

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как получилось сделать с помощью такого выражения

```
let reg = /^([a-z_]|[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\s)*([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+$/;
```